# processing on tensor ouput keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to create a pose estimation network using CNNs. The steps are as follows:

1. Generate heatmap from a CNN network.
2. Extract the key points to create a skeleton.
3. Feed this skeleton and another set of real skeletons as input to a discriminator which will decide whether the input is a skeleton or not.

My question is when I create a keras model, I get CNN model output as tensor and not an image. I know how to create key points on an image but not on a tensor. Since when I compile my model, I just give input as a tensor of a specific shape and get the output as a tensor as well, I can't have an image anywhere. How can I use a tensor from CNN to extract key points to feed to discriminator?

My CNN network is:

```
def create_encoder(input_img):
    encoder = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
    encoder = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(encoder) # 112 x 112 x 64
    encoder = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder)
    encoder = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(encoder) # 28 x 28 x 64
    encoder = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder)
    encoder = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(encoder) # 14 x 14 x 32
    decoder = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder)
    decoder = UpSampling2D((2,2))(decoder) # 28 x 28 x 128
    decoder = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder)
    decoder = UpSampling2D((4, 4))(encoder) # 112 x 112 x 64
    decoder = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder)
    decoder = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(encoder) # 224 x 224 x 32
    decoder = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder) # 224 x 224 x 3
    mod = Model(input_img, decoder)
    mod.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    return mod
```

and I need to use output from this to extract keypoints and feed to discriminator:

```
def create_discriminator(encoder_out):
    discriminator = Flatten(input_shape=(224,224,3))(encoder_out)
    discriminator = LeakyReLU(0.2)(discriminator)
    discriminator = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(discriminator)
    discriminator_mod = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=discriminator)
    discriminator_mod.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    return discriminator_mod
```

To combine them, my code is:

```
encoder_mod = create_encoder(input_img)
#TODO: extract keypoints from ecoder_mod output and feed to discriminator
discriminator_mod = create_discriminator(encoder_mod.output)
```

here instead of `encoder_mod.output`, I want to extract key points and feed to the discriminator

Comment: This depends on code, how are you producing the tensors output from the model?

Comment: I updated my post and added the code I am using

Comment: Using a custom layer was the answer for me in this case.